# Kryonet RMI throw exception => loop (StackOverflowError)

Tags: java, service, rmi, kryo, kryonet

We using Kryonet to call server methods via RMI.
**If the service returns a normal value (like true/false) it is working fine.**

But when the service throws an Exception, we get an endless loop resulting in a StackOverflowError on the Server.

```
Exception in thread "Server" java.lang.StackOverflowError
at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.getRegistration(Kryo.java:472)
at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.util.DefaultClassResolver.writeClass(DefaultClassResolver.java:97)
at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.writeClass(Kryo.java:517)
at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.ObjectField.write(ObjectField.java:76)
at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.FieldSerializer.write(FieldSerializer.java:518)
at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.writeObject(Kryo.java:552)
at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.ObjectField.write(ObjectField.java:80)
at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.FieldSerializer.write(FieldSerializer.java:518)
at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.writeObject(Kryo.java:552)
at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.ObjectField.write(ObjectField.java:80)
at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.FieldSerializer.write(FieldSerializer.java:518)
```

Service:

```
public class AuthServiceImpl extends BaseServiceImpl implements AuthService {

public boolean checkLogin(String username, String password) throws Exception {
    // ...
    throw new Exception("Test");
}
```

}

Call on client:

```
Boolean state = null;
try {
    state = service.checkLogin("Test", "password");
} catch (Exception e) {
    // Login Faild
    // ...
}
return state;
```

All Classes are registered in kryo.

- Service
- Exceptions
- Types

Can't Kryonet handle exceptions over RMI?

Comment: `throws Exception` isn't very imaginative. You should define a special `LoginException` or whatever to be thrown by this interface, and throw it.

Comment: Sure, i just simplified it for the post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have probably an exception with a cause which reference itself.

If you can't handle this cause, you should enable references when initializing KryoSerialization.

```
Kryo kryo = new Kryo();
kryo.setReferences(true);
KryoSerialization serialization = new KryoSerialization(kryo);

Server server = new Server(16384, 2048, serialization);
```

Comment: This has solved the problem! - But it is still not working. No we got a deserilize-error on the client: `Caused by: com.esotericsoftware.kryo.KryoException: Class cannot be created (missing no-arg constructor): java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableRandomAccessList`

Comment: This is not related. You can look at the kryo-serializers project, or ask another question here